# iPhone dev - How far down should I cast?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, casting, arguments

If I have a method that passes an argument of type void * (UIView animation did stop method, has to be a void pointer), or of type *id*, and I know that the argument is a UIBarButton item, and I need to disable it, [barbuttonitem setEnabled:NO];, should I cast the argument to a UIControl, which is as far as I need to be able to use setEnabled (without a warning), or should I cast it all the way down to UIBarButtonItem? Why?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIBarItem` is *not* derived from `UIControl`, so casting to UIControl really isn't the correct thing to do.  It works because both classes happen to have `setEnabled:` methods.

Casts are just another form of documentation; they don't affect what happens at runtime.  If you're expecting a `UIBarItem` then cast it as such.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a UIControl.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say cast it to a UIControl, just in case the implementation changes at some point. I'd always cast to the most appropriate interface (not implementation), and UIControl is probably the way to go.

Comment: That's slightly incorrect advice, iftrue. If you are expecting a UIBarButtonItem instance, the most appropriate **interface** is UIBarButtonItem, not UIControl. 

If you're worried about the implementation changing (which you shouldn't for something like this), you especially cannot trust that it will have the same superclass.

Comment: If you code with UIControl, then you allow you to change from a UIBarButtonItem to something else (e.g. UIButton) and still have all your code work. I wouldn't worry/expect the superclass to change; in any case, all controls are subtypes of UIControl pretty much as a de-facto standard; that will never change.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is only telling the compiler that you are expecting a variable of a certain type: It does **not** cause any changes in the variable passed in. You can cast it to UIBarButtonItem without worries.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand Objective-C correctly, you can call setEnabled directly on the object; you just won't get a guarantee that the call will go through. But if you *know* that the object returned is a UIBarItem then you can call it.